# Python -> como fundir vários ficheiros csv

Tags: python, csv, merge

Eu tenho 4 pastas, e cada uma dela está recheada com csvs de 3 tipos (ap,peers,visits).

Sou iniciante em python, mas pretendia criar um script em python que fizesse merge dos ficheiros que sao peer, de maneira a ficar com 1 unico ficheiro com as linhas de todos os ficheiros peer encontrados. 
Além disto, queria acrescentar uma coluna ao header chamada "student", e para cada linha que escrevesse no ficheiro final de peers iria colocar o respectivo student no final.

```
mainfolder = sys.argv
mainfolder.pop(0)
mainfolder = mainfolder[0]
allfolders = glob.glob(mainfolder + '*\\')

with open(mainfolder + "finalpeers\\totalpeers.csv", "w") as finalPeersFile:

    newpheader = '"_id","ssid","bssid","dateTime","latitude","longitude","student"\\n'
    finalPeersFile.write(newpheader)

    for folder in allfolders:
        student = folder.split('\\')[-2]
        filesTomerge = glob.glob(folder + '*.csv')

        for filename in filesTomerge:
            if (isPeers(filename)):
                with open(filename, 'r') as p:
                    for line in p:
                        finalPeersFile.write(line)
```

O meu código até faz isso, mas como os headers são iguais e há ficheiros que apenas têem headers, fico com imensas linhas com headers repetidos. Além disso não consigo simplesmente pegar no header da primeira linha e adicionar "student" porque há um new line "escondido", penso que seja algo particular do python.
E apesar de ter o student para adicionar no final da linha, não consigo simplesmente adicionar como se o fizesse a uma string (line + student).

**Ficheiro final:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso eliminar os repetidos ou juntar(merge) os ficheiros de maneira a não colocar os headers?

p.s.: Preço desculpa se estiver a fazer uma pergunta que já tenha sido feita (apesar de eu ter procurado imenso e nenhuma me ter ajudado a resolver o problema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `new line` escondido pode ser removido de uma string por meio do método `rstrip()`.

O header dos ficheiros de entrada podem ser ignorados (pulados) por meio da chamada do método `next()`.

Vejamos:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

# Diretorio
diretorio="/tmp"

# Recupera lista de ficheiros CSV em um diretorio
ficheiros = [f for f in listdir(diretorio) if (isfile(join(diretorio, f)) and f.endswith('.csv')) ]

# Abre ficheiro de saida...
saida = open( "saida.csv", "a" )

# Para cada ficheiro...
for f in ficheiros:

    # Abra o ficheiro
    csv = open( f )

    # Ignora o header do CSV
    csv.next()

    # Calcula student...
    student = 1

    # Para cada uma das demais linhas no ficheiro...
    for linha in csv:
         linha = linha.rstrip() + ';' + str(student) + '\n';
         saida.write(linha)

    # Fecha ficheiro CSV de entrada
    csv.close()

# Fecha ficheiro CSV de saida
saida.close()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta rápida! Tive que fazer algumas alterações mas já está a funcionar como queria graças às indicações. José